# Draw connection after node is moved in d3 org chart

Tags: d3.js, d3-org-chart

I want to draw a connection between nodes (node1 and node2) after moving certain node2 to different position using custom [layout binding](https://github.com/bumbeishvili/org-chart/blob/0b70fef70f801855e335f7db061237491eaa31fd/src/d3-org-chart.js#L293) (`nodeUpdateTransform`). In the following [example](https://jsfiddle.net/8tLy4c6p/2/) the connection is drawn to origin position of the nodes. How can I adjust the connection if a node has been moved?

```
const data = [
    { customId: 1, customParentId: null, customName: 'node1' },
    { customId: 2, customParentId: 1, customName: 'node2' },
    { customId: 3, customParentId: 1, customName: 'node3' },
  ];

  chart = new d3.OrgChart()
    .nodeId((dataItem) => dataItem.customId)
    .parentNodeId((dataItem) => dataItem.customParentId)
    .nodeWidth((node) => 100)
    .nodeHeight((node) => 100)
    .nodeContent((node) => {
      return `<div customId="${node.data.customId}" 
        style="background-color:aqua;width:${node.width}px;height:${node.height}px"
      > 
           ${node.data.customName}
       </div>`;
    })
    .container('.chart-container')
    .data(data)
    .render();
  
  i=0;
  const layout = chart.layoutBindings();
  layout.top.nodeUpdateTransform = function(node){
    if(i==1){
      i+=1;
      return `translate(${(node.x-100) - node.width / 2},${node.y})`;
    }
    //console.log(node.parentNode);
    i+=1;
    return `translate(${(node.x) - node.width / 2},${node.y})`;
  }
  
  chart.layoutBindings(layout);
  chart.connections([{from:"1",to:"2",label:"Conflicts of interest"}]).render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this from looking at the [source code](https://github.com/bumbeishvili/org-chart/blob/0b70fef70f801855e335f7db061237491eaa31fd/src/d3-org-chart.js#L340) to `d3-org-chart`.  Adding this line seems to do it:

```
layout.top.linkJoinX = node => node.x - 100;
```

Running code:

```js
const data = [{
    customId: 1,
    customParentId: null,
    customName: 'node1'
  },
  {
    customId: 2,
    customParentId: 1,
    customName: 'node2'
  },
  {
    customId: 3,
    customParentId: 1,
    customName: 'node3'
  },
];

chart = new d3.OrgChart()
  .nodeId((dataItem) => dataItem.customId)
  .parentNodeId((dataItem) => dataItem.customParentId)
  .nodeWidth((node) => 100)
  .nodeHeight((node) => 100)
  .nodeContent((node) => {
    return `<div customId="${node.data.customId}" 
            style="background-color:aqua;width:${node.width}px;height:${node.height}px"
          > 
               ${node.data.customName}
           </div>`;
  })
  .container('.chart-container')
  .data(data);

i = 0;
const layout = chart.layoutBindings();
layout.top.nodeUpdateTransform = function(node) {
  if (i == 1) {
    i += 1;
    return `translate(${(node.x-100) - node.width / 2},${node.y})`;
  }
  //console.log(node.parentNode);
  i += 1;
  return `translate(${(node.x) - node.width / 2},${node.y})`;
}

layout.top.linkJoinX = node => node.x - 100;

chart.layoutBindings(layout);
setTimeout(function() {
  chart.connections([{
    from: "1",
    to: "2",
    label: "Conflicts of interest"
  }]).render();
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-org-chart@3.0.1"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-flextree@2.1.2/build/d3-flextree.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thx, I have tried some of the settings before and many showed no effect. But don't tried that one because I expected it will modify the links not the connections. For example, what does nodeLeftX modifies?

Comment: I stumbled on `linkJoinX` through experimentation.  `nodeLeftX` doesn't seem to do anything and I can't find any documentation.  Sorry, I couldn't be of more help.